# how to call EPO(European patent Office) web service to get weekly updates using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing an application which calls EPO webservice to fetch data and it inserts to the database. Plese can anyone let me know how can i get weekly updates from EPO calling their webservice using c#

Ref wsdl url : http://ops.espacenet.com/OpenPatentServices/end-of-life/webService/getPatentData?wsdl .

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying. That service is being discontinued next month (was supposed to have been quite a while ago). Consider using an [up-to- date version](http://www.epo.org/patents/patent-information/free/open-patent-services.html) instead.

Comment: Lol the URL even says it :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

We have a brand new, more powerful OPS RESTFUL service 
http://www.epo.org/searching/free/ops.html

Additionally, on the page I mentioned above, you can find 100 pages full of examples documentation on how to use OPS.

Answer (score 0):

[Study the manual](http://ops.espacenet.com/) and see if it is possible to send set the period for updates. if not then you will have to write a service or a job to fetch the data on a weekly basis.